# Loop through array in React and create elements (not list items) from it

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React and have done a fair bit of research on this. I've quickly discovered that the `map()` function is what I think I should be using for looping through an array.

But, my problem is all the examples in the React documentation and in the SO questions I've viewed use `<ul>` and `<li>` HTML elements to handle the output.

I'm not sure that my use case is "correct" as far as React structure is concerned, but, I want to output a `<div>` with some child elements each time I loop through.

Here is my static code so far:

```
const Comment = () => {
    return (
        <div className="commenter">
            <div className="commenter-inner">
                <div className="commenter-left">
                    <img src={chachi}/>
                    <p className="commenter-name">Scott Baio</p>
                </div>            
                <div className="commenter-comment">
                    <p>Ehhhh!! Joanie loves Chachi!!!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    )
  }
```

This works, but now if I have additional comments I want to be able to serve up the same block of code again but with the new commenters name, image, comment content etc.

So I've now made an array to house my multiple commenters, and things aren't really working anymore.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import fonzie from "./img/the-fonz.jpg";
import chachi from "./img/chachi.jpg";
    
const Comments = [
    {
        id: 1, 
        name: 'Hello World', 
        photo: fonzie,
        comment: 'Welcome to learning React!'
    },
    {
        id: 2, 
        name: 'Hello World', 
        photo: chachi,
        comment: 'Welcome to learning React!'
    }    
  ];


const commentEngine = props.Comments.map((comment) =>   

    <div className="commenter" key={comment.id}>
        <div className="commenter-inner">
            <div className="commenter-left">
                <img src={comment.photo}/>
                <p className="commenter-name">{comment.name}</p>
            </div>            
            <div className="commenter-comment">
                <p>{comment.comment}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
  );

class Comments extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div className="comments-section col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-sm-12">   
            <h4>Comments</h4>
            <commentEngine />
        </div>    
        );
    }
  }



export default Comments
```

At this point I'm unsure how to verify if my loop is working in the first place and how to get the output properly displaying in my app.

Any help is greatly appreciated, as is insight into whether or not this is well structured or should be separate components.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to re-use the `Comment` component with data passed by `Comments`. In React, this is done via [props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

So, you'll want to pass the images's `src`, the name, and the description:

```
const comments = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Hello World",
    photo: fonzie,
    comment: "Welcome to learning React!",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Hello World",
    photo: chachi,
    comment: "Welcome to learning React!",
  },
];

class Comments extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="comments-section col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-sm-12">
        <h4>Comments</h4>
        {comments.map((comment) => {
          return (
            <Comment
              key={comment.id} // https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html
              name={comment.name}
              imgSrc={comment.photo}
              comment={comment.comment}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Notice that I've renamed the constant array `Comments` to `comments` so that the name doesn't clash with the `Comments` component.

Then in the `Comment` component, you can access these props via the argument passed to the function component:

```
const Comment = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="commenter">
      <div className="commenter-inner">
        <div className="commenter-left">
          <img src={props.imgSrc} />
          <p className="commenter-name">{props.name}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="commenter-comment">
          <p>{props.comment}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Additionally, we can make the code a bit less verbose by leveraging [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring):

```
class Comments extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="comments-section col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-sm-12">
        <h4>Comments</h4>
        {comments.map(({ id, name, photo, comment }) => {
          return (
            <Comment key={id} name={name} imgSrc={photo} comment={comment} />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ...

const Comment = ({ imgSrc, name, comment }) => {
    return (
      <div className="commenter">
        <div className="commenter-inner">
          <div className="commenter-left">
            <img src={imgSrc} />
            <p className="commenter-name">{name}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="commenter-comment">
            <p>{comment}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Comment: thank you very much! not just for the answer but the comments and links your provided as well. Super helpful and gets me going with this issue while setting me up to re-use this way of thinking for future use cases. Can't thank you enough, have a great day!

Comment: @HisPowerLevelIsOver9000 I'm glad I could help! I'd suggest reading through the official React tutorial, it goes through the most important concepts in practice :) https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

```
const commentEngine = (comments) => {   
    return comments.map((comment)=>{
         return (
          <div className="commenter" key={comment.id}>
          <div className="commenter-inner">
            <div className="commenter-left">
                <img src={comment.photo}/>
                <p className="commenter-name">{comment.name}</p>
            </div>            
            <div className="commenter-comment">
                <p>{comment.comment}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div> 
  )})

class Comments extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div className="comments-section col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-sm-12">   
            <h4>Comments</h4>
            {commentEngine(props.Comment)}
        </div>    
        );


    }
  }
```

Now when you render Comments you need to pass the Comment props.

```
<Comments Comment={Comments}/>
```

Comment: Perhaps `renderComments` should be `commentEngine` or the other way around?

Answer (score -1):

#### USAGECASE

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import fonzie from "./img/the-fonz.jpg";
import chachi from "./img/chachi.jpg";
    
const Comments = [
    {
        id: 1, 
        name: 'Hello World', 
        photo: fonzie,
        comment: 'Welcome to learning React!'
    },
    {
        id: 2, 
        name: 'Hello World', 
        photo: chachi,
        comment: 'Welcome to learning React!'
    }    
  ];


const Comment = props =>
    const {comment} = props;
    <div className="commenter" key={comment.id}>
        <div className="commenter-inner">
            <div className="commenter-left">
                <img src={comment.photo}/>
                <p className="commenter-name">{comment.name}</p>
            </div>            
            <div className="commenter-comment">
                <p>{comment.comment}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
  );

class Comments extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div className="comments-section col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-sm-12">   
            <h4>Comments</h4>
            {Comments.map((comment,index) => <Comment key={'[CUSTOM_KEY]'} props={comment}> )}
        </div>    
        );
    }
  }



export default Comments
```

#### ANSWER

1. First of all, You can use `index` parameter in `Array.map`
2. Secondly, if you want to use list component you can make Single Component like `<Comment comment={comment}>` and you can use it with `Array.map`
3. And It is very good to study `How to make functional component`

Comment: Notice that the `key` should be set in the rendered array, so in `Comments` where you do `.map`. Also, perhaps you meant: `<Comment key={comment.id} comment={comment} />`

Comment: Yeah, Exactly I mean that!